# Computed property on key of object passed as component parameter

Tags: ember.js, service, computed-properties

I have a messages service that will eventually get messages saved in the database and set them globally for the user but for now I have them set like so

```
  messages: [
    Ember.Object.create({
      id: 1,
      name: "Out Bid",
      body: "You've been out bid on an item",
      read: false,
      seen: false
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
      id: 2,
      name: "Out Bid",
      body: "You've been out bid on an item, You've been out bid on an item",
      read: true,
      seen: false
    })
  ],
```

I have some computed that will tell me how many of these messages have not been marked as `seen` and when I click on this bubble that shows if that number is over 0 I go to a `messages` route.
In the `messages` route I inject the `messages` service and set the model equal to the messages that the service has in it

```
model() {
    return this.get('messages').get('messages');
}
```

This route displays the messages in an each loop that renders a component

```
{{#each model key="id" as |message|}}
    {{message-item message=message}}
{{/each}}
```

In the component I am trying to add the `unread` class like so

```
classNameBindings: ['unread'],
unread: Ember.computed('message.unread',function(){
    return this.get('message').get('read') === false;
}),
```

And that is working, however when I fire the click action to show the message in a modal and therefore mark it as `read` the computed is not updating

```
click() {
    var message = this.get('message');
    this.get('notification').notify({message: message.get('body')});
    message.set('read',true);
}
```

If I `console.log` the value of `message.get('read')` before and after I set it, I see that it is properly being set, but the template is not updating the computed to remove the `unread` class after it's marked read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You watch wrong property. Watch `read` instead of `unread`:

```
classNameBindings: ['unread'],
unread: Ember.computed('message.read',function(){
    return this.get('message').get('read') === false;
}),
```

Comment: You code all day long every day and expect not to miss little things like this!